# How to search in a particular column in a Listview?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listview, textbox

I am trying to adjust a code that I have found on a forum and so far my little tweaks have made the code work for my form. However, I am only allowed to search Column 0 on my listview when I want it to search Column 1 and Column 2 (at least column 1). Does anyone know how to adjust my code so I can search a name in Column 1 and/or column 2? A

Also the line where it starts "Console" has a "Expression expected" issue. How do I end this expression?

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim itm As ListViewItem
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To InstitutionAddContactListView.Items.Count - 1
        itm = InstitutionAddContactListView.SelectedItems(i)
        Console.WriteLine(ContactFirstColumnHeader = {1} ContactLastColumnHeader = {2},itm.SubItems(1),itm.SubItems(2))
        InstitutionAddContactListView.Items(i).Selected = False
        InstitutionAddContactListView.Items(i).BackColor = Color.White
    Next

    With InstitutionAddContactListView
        itm = .FindItemWithText(TextBox1.Text, False, 0, True)


        If Not itm Is Nothing Then
            .Items.Item(itm.Index).BackColor = Color.Blue
            .Items.Item(itm.Index).EnsureVisible()
        Else
            MsgBox("No Record Found!")
            For i = 0 To InstitutionAddContactListView.Items.Count - 1
                InstitutionAddContactListView.Items(i).Selected = False
                InstitutionAddContactListView.Items(i).BackColor = Color.White
            Next
            .Items(0).EnsureVisible()
            .Items.Item(0).BackColor = Color.Blue
            TextBox1.SelectionStart = 0
            TextBox1.Focus()
        End If
    End With
    itm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With InstitutionAddContactListView
        itm = .FindItemWithText(TextBox1.Text, TRUE, 0, True)